# Add Image to Google Maps Marker Title in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I dont want to change the marker's image
I just want to add an image to the title so it looks nice

something like this "Read More" image..

[image]

is there any way to do so

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Title is called `InfoWindow`. To achieve your custom window, you need:

1) Create class which implement `GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter` interface. Something like this (in this case just `TextView`):

```
public class MapItemAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

  TextView tv;

  public MapItemAdapter(Context context) {
      tv = new TextView(context);
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
      tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
      tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
  }


  @Override
  public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
      tv.setText(marker.getTitle());
      return tv;
  }

  @Override
  public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
      return null;
  }
}
```

2) Set adapter to `GoogleMap` you've received in `onMapReady()` callback:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap map) {
    ...
    map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MapItemAdapter(this));
    ...
}
```

Comment: Where the image can be set?

Comment: If you want just image, replace `TextView` with `ImageView`. If you want to show more complex window, create custom layout and place `ImageView` inside. Created view just return in `getInfoWindow` method.